# Scala class instantiation on run time design

Tags: scala

I am having a design issue here. I have the following below structure.

```
trait Table
object Table1 extends Table
object Table2 extends Table
// and so on till Table200
```

I have command line interface where the user specifies the table name that needs to be executed. So the problem I am having is instantiating the classes based on the table name(type String) specified by the user. I am looking for a solution without the use of reflection.

Comment: Doesn't seem related to `apache-spark`

Comment: removed the tag

Comment: How about a Hashmap, from String ("23") or Int (23) to Table23? Or an Array of 201 tables, and accessing them by Index? A dummy table 0 would be useful then. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some kind of "registry" if you want to avoid using reflection:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

object MyApp {

  // Create some kind of "registry"
  private val TableByName: mutable.Map[String, Table] = mutable.Map()

  // Create a lookup method:
  def lookup(name: String): Option[Table] = TableByName.get(name)

  // Each table would register itself
  trait Table {
    TableByName.put(this.toString, this)
    override def toString: String = this.getClass.getSimpleName.replace("$", "")
  }

  // Instantiate each object after declaring it, or else it won't "register"
  object Table1 extends Table; Table1
  object Table2 extends Table; Table2
  // ...

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // Now we can lookup our table in the registry by name
    val result: Option[Table] = lookup("Table2")
    println(result)
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am adding to my design now but I don't see why it won't work.

Comment: How do I instantiate each object after declaring it. Is that possible? I tried how you did it and it won't compile.

Comment: The code I posted does that (notice the reference to each `Table` after it is defined) and works well for me. What's the compilation error you're seeing and for which line?

Comment: So you're snippet works since you wrapped them in another object (My App). In my case imagine having each of those objects, Table1 and Table2 be in separate files.

Comment: To give you more context, my project is a spark based app. Each of these Tables I am referring to have spark table definitions and so on to build the data frames

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> trait Table
// defined trait Table    
scala> object Table1 extends Table
// defined object Table1   
scala> object Table2 extends Table
// defined object Table2
scala> val name = "Table2"
// name: String = Table2


scala> val map = Map (1 -> Table1, 2 -> Table2)
// map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Table] = Map(1 -> Table1$@51549af8, 2 -> Table2$@394542f5)    
scala> def getTable (s: String) : Option [Table] = map.get (s.replaceAll ("^Table", "").toInt)
// getTable: (s: String)Option[Table]    
scala> getTable (name)
// res0: Option[Table] = Some(Table2$@394542f5)
```

Using an array would be similar:

```
val tblarr = Array[Table] (Table1, Table2)
val usertbl = tblarr(name.replaceAll ("^Table", "").toInt - 1)
```

or, with a dummy table at index 0, without the error prone -1 operation (easy to forget).

Comment: You're solution won't work. Like mentioned about there about 200 tables. I DO NOT want to have Map that is that big

Comment: I want it so that it can self-add to the Map on initialization. Like the solution by the other member below.But in that solution, the problem I came across is intianiating the object

Comment: 200 isn't a big number for a Map. The size of memory for the tables, you need anyhow. The map only stores a little overhead for each member as it contains references, not duplicates. Why do you believe it wouldn't work? You see, that the code compiled in the REPL and that it worked?

Comment: You're right 200 is not a lot in a Map but I really don't want to have a file where the Map is initialized with 200 lines or more in the future and the team members in my project forget to add that line. It's pain to maintain the Map. Before we used to have List. I am looking some way to self register to the map on run time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
trait Table
class Table1 extends Table
class Table2 extends Table

object Table   { 
  def apply (kind: String) = kind match {
    case "Table1" => new Table1() 
    case "Table2" => new Table2()
  } 
} 

Table("Table1")
```

I believe that you can read the input from the cli pass that value while creating the object.

Comment: It won't work, the problem again here is that I have over 200 implementations of Table which means that pattern match is going to be useless.